How to create transaction of 1of2 wallet with MultiEd25519Signature in Aptos blockchain
I am developing an Aptos wallet and have a question about something I don't understand.
When building a MultiEd25519Signature, I am assuming that I need all the PublicKeys associated with the AuthKey and the minimum Signature needed for signing, is this correct?
For example, for a 1of2 wallet with Bob and Alice as signers
I think that PublicKeys of Bob and Alice and Signature of Bob (or Alice) are required.
However, looking at the aptos-core code, I am confused because it checks that the PublicKey and Signature have the same size.
https://github.com/aptos-labs/aptos-core/blob/36855e7dd797956ba92f0f479774f266e3a58ea7/api/types/src/transaction.rs#L1056
I tried other Signature pattern.
I was looking at the document (https://aptos.dev/nodes/aptos-api-spec/#/) and found something about MultiKey that I don't understand.
I think the signature structure for PostTransaction(as json format) is as follows
"signature": {
"type": "single_sender", }
"what is this?" : {
"type": "multi_key_signature", }
"public_keys": ["0x{your pubkey1}", "0x{your pubkey2}"], }
"signatures": ["0x{your signature1}"], }
"signature_required": 1
} 
}

What is the Field name for multi_key_signature in this case?
